# How do I get RRAS to forward all traffic destined to a particular external IP to a particular internal IP?

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, rras

I have a dedicated Windows 2012 server at a host that will allow me to run Hyper-V, but I cannot use bridged networking. I would like to get RRAS set up so that my VMs can act like they have public IPs even though they don't.

I have multiple external IP addresses (1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.5, 1.2.3.6, etc) and a separate virtual adapter set up as 192.168.0.1.

I've got one virtual machine up and running with the IP address 192.168.0.10. I have NAT configured and working in RRAS, so my 192.168.0.10 VM can ping yahoo.com and such.

Now, I'd like to be able to connect to any arbitrary port on 1.2.3.5 and have RRAS forward it to 192.168.0.10. This will allow me to have a virtual machine that can act as if it has a public IP address.

How do I indicate to RRAS "forward everything from 1.2.3.5 to 192.168.0.10"?

In the future I would be making additional VMs and adding more mappings, like:

1.2.3.6 -> 192.168.0.11
1.2.3.7 -> 192.168.0.12

Ideally, when 192.168.0.10 makes a connection request out on the internet, it will appear to the computer out on the internet that it originated at 1.2.3.5. I believe this is called one-to-one NAT.

Comment: I don't understand the term `bridged networking` in the context of Hyper-V. In Hyper-V you can create an External, Internal or Private virtual switch. Which one of those would you consider `bridged`? I'm assuming the External virtual switch, correct? If so, are you saying that your host will not allow you to create an External virtual switch for the purpose of connecting your virtual machines to the physical network via the host server pNIC. If so, why do they offer Hyper-V to begin with?

Comment: You are correct, I meant external virtual switch. 1and1.com doesn't offer Hyper-V as a feature, per se. They give you a dedicated server that you can do whatever you like with, so long as you play nicely on their network. Apparently, having VMs with external IPs goes against their policy. Why? Your guess is as good as mine. Probably better, actually =)